# What is the most efficient way to see every ending?

Tags: beyond-two-souls

I reached the conclusion of Beyond: Two Souls and was presented with several choices that clearly influenced the ending I got. I realise I can replay the final chapter and make different choices to see different endings however some of the endings are influenced by the events of previous chapters (mainly Navaho and Homeless I think.)

Some googling has revealed there are 24 endings in total depending on certain choices made at critical points in the game. While I did enjoy the game the interaction is minimal and the repetition is high on multiple play throughs.

What I want to know is what the most efficient way to play through the game in order see all the endings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So some further research revealed that to get the 'All Endings' trophy you need to do the following:

**Saved All Characters Playthrough.**

At the end of the playthrough, you need to pick between "Beyond"and "Life", just select the option "Life". Then eventually it will merge to the Epilogue mission where you need to select how you want to continue. Start by selecting "Alone" and watch the cut scene and then eventually the long credits. To see the next ending just go to chapter select and pick the "Epilogue" mission and put the save "On" option. The "Epilogue" mission will start again but this time when prompted select the next one down in the list being "Zoey" and continue this method....

Alone

Zoey

Jay

Ryan

Replay "Black Sun" mission but choose the "Beyond" option at the end

**Everyone Is Dead Playthrough**

At the end of your second playthrough, you need to pick between "Beyond" and "Life", just select the option "Life". Then eventually it will merge to the Epilogue mission where you need to select how you want to continue. Start by selecting "Alone" and watch the cut scene and then eventually the long credits. To see the next ending just go to chapter select and pick the "Epilogue" mission and put the save "On" option. The "Epilogue" mission will start again but this time when prompted select the next one down in the list being "Zoey" and continue this method....

Alone

Zoey

Jay

Replay "Black Sun" mission but choose the "Beyond" option at the end

**Miscellaneous Endings**

The final ending is where Jodie dies in the fight against the monsters, in front of the Black Sun. Reply the "Black Sun" mission and basically just don't follow the on screen prompts by not pressing any buttons once the entities appear in front of the black sun. You will get a very short, "dark" beyond ending then.

Full credit to [PS3trophies.org](http://ps3trophies.com/forums/showwiki.php?title=PS3-Trophy-Guides:Beyond:-Two-Souls-Trophy-Guide)'s beyond wiki by Marccap